# Sign an NFT asset with an Ethereum address

Tags: signature, nft

Is it available an Ethereum application that allow the owner to let "sign" his NFT asset by other addresses? If not would it be possible to develop it?

Comment: When you say *sign* you mean a cryptographic signature?

Comment: Who "signs" the NFT is the owner of the address I would add to a specific field in the NFT metadata, it would appear along with the creator address. A real life example could be a basketball I own and that I make sign by a famous player.

Comment: In an EthGlobal's hackathon about NFT there were a couple of finalist that were designing protocols for signatures https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPa3UsuTAsw.

Comment: Super interesting demo showcase. It seems that hashink project will include the functionality I described. I'll get in touch with them to understand their approach

Comment: It would be nice to answer the question if you find out more details about the project.